# Implementing CORS in Play Framework 2.4 for Scala

Tags: scala, cors, playframework-2.4

I am not yet succeeding in making CORS requests work in my project, basically a Play server and an AngularJS web client.

Since there are many variables to take into consideration, I would like first to be sure that everything is ok at least on the Play server side. But, my fault, the [Play 2.4 documentation on CORS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter) is not enough to help me figure out a concrete use case.

Two basic questions:

1. Creating a Filters class in the root of your project (see [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter#Enabling-the-CORS-filter)): where to place the provided code? Not sure what the "root of your project" is, I added the class to my controller in `app/controllers/Mycontr.scala`
2. The points described in the documentation are enough? Or other parts need to be touched as well, for example routing in `app/conf/routes`

Tried to find a complete tutorial, but had no luck for Play 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"root of your project" means a directory which corresponds to the package root. It is `app/` by default, `src/main/scala/` when using [default sbt layout](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anatomy#Default-SBT-layout). That's all.

Comment: Ok, I placed the code in a newly created `app/root.scala` and now it works. So no other parts need to be touched server side in my case; and no need as well to change the AngularJS client side.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same, issue, it keeps saying:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/fetchBetween.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I added `Filters.scala` to my `app/` folder, and added `filters` to `libraryDependencies`, this is my config in `application.conf`:

```
play.filters.cors {

  pathPrefixes = ["/fetchBetween"]

  allowedOrigins = ["*"]

  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]

  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]

  preflightMaxAge = 3 days

}
```

Comment: This spot is meant for answers, not questions.